# Recursive listing of files in a directory matching a pattern

Tags: python

I am trying to recursively list all file names that are in sub directories called Oracle (but not list files in other sub directories).

I have the following code:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"Y:\Data\MXD_DC\DataSourceChange", topdown=True):
    for name in dirs:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, 'Oracle'):
            for filename in files:
                fullpath = os.path.join(root, filename)
                print "FullPath is: " + fullpath
```

I can only get it to list all file names of all sub directories. It does not even go to the sub directory called Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, when you find a directory named Oracle, you list the files that are at the same level in the hierachy instead of listing the files *contained* in the Oracle folder, because the tuple returned by `os.walk` contains directories and files at same level.

You have 2 ways to list the expected files:

- only use dirnames from `walk` and use `listdir` once you have found an Oracle folder

  ```
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"Y:\Data\MXD_DC\DataSourceChange", topdown=True):
  for name in dirs:
      if name == 'Oracle':
          path = os.path.join(root, name)
          for filename in os.listdir(path):
              fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)
              print "FullPath is: " + fullpath
  ```
- ignore dirnames, use last component from root and test if it is Oracle:

  ```
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"Y:\Data\MXD_DC\DataSourceChange", topdown=True):
      if os.path.basename(root) == 'Oracle':
          for filename in files:
              fullpath = os.path.join(root, filename)
              print "FullPath is: " + fullpath
  ```

Comment: That worked great with a minor correction.
    fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to list the files in a particular directory you can use

```
import os
os.listdir("Oracle")
```

to print the directories from a script use this

```
import os
print "%s" %os.listdir("Oracle")
```

Comment: Well I have to work with files in that particular directory. And the directory called Oracle may not necessarily be at the root level. It could be in one of the sub directories.